# model binding behavior varie between Controller and ControllerBase with [ApiController]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I use asp dotnet core V6 (that is the preview version).

I have two identical methods, one in an MVC controller, the other in an Api Controller. The signature of the methods are:

for MVC

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Variable(Models.DTParameters dtp)
```

for api

```
[HttpGet]
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
[Route("api/Select/Variable")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Variable([FromQuery] Models.DTParameters dtp)
```

the methods are called by jquery `$.ajax`

for MVC:

```
{
     method: 'POST',
     url: '/Select/Variable'
}
```

for api:

```
{
     method: 'GET',
     url: '/api/Select/Variable'
}
```

| MVC | api |
| --- | --- |
| All is fine | Only the simple property (draw, start, length) are binded.the others (search...) are null. |
|  | If I try with `method='POST'` and `[FromBody]`, I end with an error: "Not supported media type" |

Any idea on how to get ApiController correctly bind `DTParameters` ?

----- EDIT 1

it works if I remove the [ApiController] attibute from my api controller:

```
//[ApiController]
public class SelectController : ControllerBase
```

for my mvc controller the declaration is:

```
public class SelectController : Controller
```

----- EDIT 2

with [ApiController] and the following declaration:

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("application/json")]
[Route("api/Select/Variable")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Variable(Models.DTParameters dtp)
```

I now get an error 400:

> {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-9753afa4b5fc5ed24f3605c3edd51d8e-25872b0ff804e179-00","errors":{"$.order[0].dir":["The JSON value could not be converted to adaptator.wgui.Models.DTOrderDir. Path: $.order[0].dir | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 151."]}}

where position value 151 correponds to the " after the last c in

```
"order":[{"column":0,"dir":"asc"}]
```

It seems that the binder can't handles the DTOrderDir enum.

----- ANNEXE

where DTParmeters is:

```
public class DTParameters {
    public int Draw { get; set; }
    public DTColumn[] Columns { get; set; }
    public DTOrder[] Order { get; set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public DTSearch Search { get; set; }
    public DTKeyValue[] MoreForSearch { get; set; }
}
public class DTKeyValue {
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
public class DTColumn {
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Searchable { get; set; }
    public bool Orderable { get; set; }
    public DTSearch Search { get; set; }
}
public class DTOrder {
    public int Column { get; set; }
    public DTOrderDir Dir { get; set; }
}
public enum DTOrderDir {
    asc,
    desc
}
public class DTSearch {
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool Regex { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just fix action attributes. Remove ALL attributes except Route

mvc

```
[Route("~/Select/Variable")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Variable(Models.DTParameters dtp)
```

api

```
[Route("~/api/Select/Variable")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Variable( Models.DTParameters dtp)
```

and fix ajax

mvc

```
{
     method: 'POST',
     url: '/Select/Variable'
}
```

api

```
{
     method: 'POST',
     url: '/Select/Variable'
}
```

if you don't have [ApiController] attribute use this for API

```
{
     method: 'POST',
     url: '/Api/Select/Variable'
}
```

Comment: same error (415) "not supported media type"

Comment: it works if i remove [ApiController] from my controller

Comment: but, so what is the purpose of [ApiController] ?

Comment: None already. In the last versions of Net it is obsolete.  You can use Controller instead of   ControllerBase

Comment: ok, may I ask you a reference for [ApiController] being obsolete ?

Comment: You can keep it if it is very important for you. It is still working for backword compatibility. I am sorry but I don't keep any links.

Comment: In net core you  just  can configure in startup if you want controllers or controller with views.